# Найдите все пифагоровы тройки, в которых все числа находятся в диапазоне [1; 5000]

Tags: python, математика

Пифагоровой тройка назовём тройку чисел *(a, b, c)*, такую что `a ≤ b ≤ с` и `a2+b2=c2`. Найдите все пифагоровы тройки, в которых все числа находятся в диапазоне **[1; 5000]**. Запишите в ответе количество подходящих троек, а затем – значение c для тройки, в которой сумма `a+b+c` максимальна.

Помогите пожалуйста, код нужен на python, в ответе к заданию (**5681 4988**)

```
k = 0
for m in range(1, 5000+1):
    if (a < 5000) and (a ** 2 + b ** 2 == c ** 2):
        print(a,b,c)
        k += 1
print(k)
```

Comment: А чем помочь? Про цикл for и сами можете прочитать.

Comment: Сейчас отредактирую вопрос и сами все увидите, я пытался делать не получается, даже сначала делал до 1000 чтобы он мне хотя бы вывел это количество пифагоровых троек, до 1000 их вроде 179 точно уже не помню, ну так вот код даже так не правильно выводит, поэтому сюда и написал

Comment: Не, картинки никто смотреть не будет, код вставляйте текстом.

Comment: все, добавил код вот смотрите, кстати еще там по заданию нужно еще вывести максимальное значение с максимальной пифагоровой тройки, получается просто через функцию ( max() ) сделать или как?

Comment: код, который я представил сверху вообще не правильно выводит, он для каждого числа до 1000 выводит пифагоровы тройки, которых даже не существует

Comment: Что-то я не очень понимаю, какое отношение имеет этот код к этой постановке задачи

Comment: Все пифагоровы тройки можно сгенерировать в трёх циклах с проверкой. Но выгоднее посмотреть в википедию и использовать формулы для генерации оттуда.

Comment: если вы знаете как это сделать, то помогите пожалуйста, я не знаю как решить эту задачу, так то просто так и я рассуждать могу

Comment: @Maks Я вам написал ответ-подсказку, вам осталось только код по этой схеме написать

Comment: @CrazyElf а у вас с ответом который я написал выше сошлось? если да, то буду думать как это написать

Comment: @Maks Да, с ответом сошлось

Answer (score 6):

Ну, я написал код, но пока вам его не покажу - это всё-таки учебное задание. Но дам подсказки:

- перебирайте в цикле `a` в указанном вам диапазоне `[1,5000]`
- перебирайте в цикле `b`, учитывая, что оно тоже должно быть в диапазоне `[1,5000]` и кроме того, что `a <= b`
- `c` перебирать не нужно, его можно вычислить зная `a` и `b` из уравнения, которое вам дано
- вычисленное `c` нужно проверить на попадание в диапазон и на то, что получилось вообще целое число
- если `c` получилось подходящее - увеличивайте счётчик, кроме того, сравните получающееся `a+b+c` с ранее запомненным значением (сначала запомните 0, как и в счётчик), если оно больше - запомните его и запомните `c`
- после окончания циклов выведите значение счётчика и запомненного `c`

Вышеуказанные два вложенных цикла + логика внутри них работают 8 секунд в Google Colab, этого вполне достаточно, чтобы дальше код можно было особо не оптимизировать.

Вот если бы было три вложенных цикла по 5000 значений, то это бы работало конкретно долго.

P.S. Ответ у меня сошёлся с указанным в задании.

Ну раз GrAnd выложил код, добавлю и я свой. Он прям "в лоб" написан, без особых оптимизаций, разве что из цикла я вынес `a ** 2` и перебор `b` прерываю, если `c` вышло из диапазона. В функцию вынесено, чтобы можно было при желании обернуть в `numba.njit`:

```
def find():
    count = 0
    max3 = 0
    max_c = 0
    for a in range(1, 5001):
        a2 = a * a
        for b in range(a, 5001):
            b2 = b * b
            c = (a2 + b2) ** 0.5
            if c > 5000:
                break
            if c == int(c):
                count += 1
                if a+b+c > max3:
                    max3 = a+b+c
                    max_c = c
    return count, int(max_c)

print(find())
```

Comment: попробовал сравнить код на питоне и плюсах, который прям по этому алгоритму написанный с маленькой микрооптимизацией.  питоновский код - около 5 секунд, на си - 0.05. Прям ужасЪ.

Comment: @KoVadim Если вынести в отдельную функцию и обернуть в `numba.njit`, то работает за 30мс, т.е. сопоставимо или даже быстрее чем плюсы ))  Питон удобен для прототипирования, а если нужна скорость, то у него тоже есть методы

Comment: я поминаю любовь к питону, но тут вряд ли питон сможет обогнать код на си, даже на нумбе. Но мне прототипировать на си быстрее числодробилки

Comment: переписал на numba (дописал несколько строк) - 0.75с. Не плохо, очень не плохо, но "маловато будет":)

Comment: @KoVadim Ну, я добавил код, раз GrAnd тоже код выложил. У меня с `numba` тут 30мс в колабе выходит, хм. Ну я кое-что оптимизировал тут, но не сильно же.

Comment: `c == int(c)` -> `c.is_integer()`

Answer (score 4):

Используя генерацию [Пифагоровых троек](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0#%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA), вот что у меня получилось:

```
MAX = 5000

triplets = set()
for n in range(1, int((MAX+1)**0.5)+1):
    for m in range(n+1, MAX+1, 2):
        for k in range(1, MAX+1):
            c = k * (m*m + n*n)
            if c > MAX: break
            b = k * 2 * m * n
            a = k * (m*m - n*n)
            triplets.add(tuple(sorted((a,b,c))))
        if k == 1:
            break

print(len(triplets), max((a+b+c, c) for a,b,c in triplets)[1])
```

В Google Colab отработало за 0.009 секунды

Comment: Ну, тут сплошные оптимизации, понятно, что совсем быстро работает ))

Comment: @CrazyElf Не... С оптимизациями (если вынести повторяющиеся вычисления из-под циклов) можно ещё 10-15% скостить. ))

Answer (score 1):

До кучи:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    while b > 0:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

maxsum = 0
maxc = 0
cnt = 0
for m in range(2, 72):
    mm = m * m
    n = m - 1
    while (n > 0):
        if mm + n*n <= 5000 and gcd(n,m)==1:
            a = mm - n * n
            b = 2 * n * m
            c = n*n + mm
            for k in range(1, 5000//c+1):
                aa = k * a
                bb = k * b
                cc = k * c
                if aa + bb + cc > maxsum:
                    maxc = cc
                    maxsum = aa + bb + cc
                cnt += 1
        n -= 2

print(cnt, maxc)
```